# Angular : mat select search with infinite scroll not patching record after selecting

Tags: angular, angular-material, infinite-scroll, angular9, mat-select

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-search-with-infinity-scroll-4fgygy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

In this mat select search and infinite scroll is used but if I search the data and clicked it will automatically getting reset (eg. Option 142 which is I typed it getting reset after selecting the value, how to solve this issue?)